# How to find average price to a grouped range when my price is in a different table with Apex Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

[Pic of SCORE_T table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk1ay.png)  I'm trying to find a way to code my average price into ranges I established from a separate table. So, my points which I used to form a range are from my POINTS_T table, and I used the number of occurrences to establish one column by using COUNT(*). I am now trying to find the average price per range, but my price is in the WINE table and I am having trouble since I am using a subquery and don't know where to include it. I have attached two pictures, one of which is my original code with no errors (since I did not try to include the average price) and the 2nd which includes my attempt at including it in the subquery.

Here is my code I have so far (that does not include my attempt at average price).

```
SELECT t.range as "Score Range", COUNT(*) as "Number of Occurrences" 
FROM (
  SELECT Case  
    when SCORE_T.Points between 95 and 100 then '95-100'
    when SCORE_T.Points between 90 and 94 then '90-94'
    when SCORE_T.Points between 85 and 89 then '85-89'
    when SCORE_T.Points between 80 and 84 then '80-84'
    end as RANGE
  FROM SCORE_T) t
GROUP BY t.range
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
;
```

And here is what I have with my attempt, which produces an error.

```
SELECT t.range as "Score Range", COUNT(*) as "Number of Occurrences"
FROM (
  SELECT Case  
    when SCORE_T.Points between 95 and 100 then '95-100'
    when SCORE_T.Points between 90 and 94 then '90-94'
    when SCORE_T.Points between 85 and 89 then '85-89'
    when SCORE_T.Points between 80 and 84 then '80-84'
    end as RANGE, avg(WINE.Price) as "Average Price of Wine"
  FROM SCORE_T, WINE) t
GROUP BY t.range
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the table definition of WINE and SCORE_T and what is the relationship between two.

Comment: Can you post some example data of your `WINE` and `SCORE_T` table? The error is in your subquery where you use an aggregate (avg) while not grouping and your are also writing `, WINE` after `FROM SCORE_T` as if you want to select from both those tables at the same time.

Comment: We cannot see the links to the attached pictures

Comment: The relationship is a foreign key identified by Wine_ID between the tables WINE and SCORE_T. I'm sorry about the pics, they were just pics of the code I wrote out. I can post example data from each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `JOIN` and you are using `avg()` with no `GROUP BY`.  I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT sw.range as Score_Range,
       COUNT(*) as Number_of_Occurrences,
       AVG(sw.Price) as Average_Price
FROM (SELECT (Case when s.Points between 95 and 100 then '95-100'
                   when s.Points between 90 and 94 then '90-94'
                   when s.Points between 85 and 89 then '85-89'
                   when s.Points between 80 and 84 then '80-84'
              end) as RANGE,
           w.Price as Price
     FROM SCORE_T s JOIN
          WINE w
          ON s.? = w.?  -- what are the JOIN keys???
    ) sw
GROUP BY sw.range
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the column that links the score and wine table.

Comment: Thank you so much! Question answered, I appreciate the help. Is there a way for me to mark this [Solved] and upvote your answer? It says I do not have enough rep points.